# Unable to copy sqlite database from assets to internal memory

Tags: android, android-sqlite

We are trying to copy `sqlite` database stored in assets folder to local directory on actual phone but unable to do so. `CheckDatabase` tails us that database exists but code fails when we try to read data from phone. ( Also tried to view database through `DDMS` it doesn't show there)

Phone we have with OS 2.3.4

Saw that various folks have complained on `StackOverflow`  but did not find any solution.

Is this related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=949

Also tried below library

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Sample code provided in this also fails while copying database and gives below error

```
sqlite3_open_v2("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.sqliteassethelper.example/files/northwind", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device

Comment: @StevenByle - I have gone through this link earlier but yield same result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this library , it will do the magic for you 
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper
Hope this would help you