# Android - Add sqlite database to app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I would like to add a database to my Android app which should not be created on runtime (must be preloaded). I have an existing sqlite database and i just want to integrate it with my app. How do I do this? I've googled but the tutorials I see are about creating the database on runtime.

Comment: Your app could copy the database file from its assets to the DB location on the device (see `Context.getDatabasePath`) after installation.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738956/11654) for an example.