# Copy SQlite DB to public directory (non rooted devices)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using SQLiteOpenHelper to create my database. I changed the constructor like this:

```
public SQLite(Context context){
    super(context, "/mnt/sdcard"+DATABASE_NAME+".db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

The database is created in the public directory just fine. The problem is that when I try to execute functions, I cant change the database to the one I created in the public directory. How can I change this? eg:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    Log.i("DB PATH", db.getPath());
}
```

This prints out:

```
DB PATH - /data/data/package_name/databases/database_name
```

I need this to print out the path to the public database.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Copy private DB to public directory instead

Changed constructor to this:

```
public SQLite(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Used the code from the link that Geralt suggested:

```
private void copyDataBase(String dbname) throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(dbname);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = "/data/data/com.sample.view/databases/" + dbname;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Here is the stack trace of what happens:

```
04-15 09:57:55.275: W/ResourceType(11994): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
04-15 09:57:55.275: W/ResourceType(11994): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
04-15 09:57:55.275: W/ResourceType(11994): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
04-15 09:57:55.320: W/System.err(11994): java.io.FileNotFoundException: aCollectDatabase
04-15 09:57:55.320: W/System.err(11994): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
04-15 09:57:55.320: W/System.err(11994): at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
04-15 09:57:55.320: W/System.err(11994): at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
04-15 09:57:55.320: W/System.err(11994): at co.za.datasolve.acollect.ACollectActivity.copyDataBase(ACollectActivity.java:184)
04-15 09:57:55.320: W/System.err(11994): at co.za.datasolve.acollect.ACollectActivity.onCreate(ACollectActivity.java:153)
```

And this is the problem line:

```
InputStream myInput = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(dbname);
```

Does anyone have suggestions of how I can fix this?

Comment: So you want to create database in another directory?

Comment: The constructor is creating the DB in another directory, I need to use that database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I changed the constructor like this:

Problem is that in constructor you're specifing only **database name** and *not path*. Database created by `SQLiteOpenHelper` will be placed always in internal storage for security reasons - you can't change this logic. It's build-in logic by OS.

All what you can do is explicitly copy your database into another directory.

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device) you'll find how to copy database.

**Update:**

Here is how to get database path:

```
String path = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("your_database_name");
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. I tried using your suggestion, but I keep getting an error. See my edit please

Comment: @Lunchbox com.sample.view this only example package you need to use your package. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere) is how you can obtain your package name.

Comment: Sorry, I copied that from the link you sent me. I am entering my correct path and package name

Comment: The problem is this:InputStream myInput = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(dbname);

Comment: @Lunchbox FileNotFoundException means that file is not in provided path. Check your db path if it's correct.

Comment: In my SQLite class I checked it like this: Log.d("DB Path", db.getPath());, I try to check it in DDMS, but I cant open the path, probably because I am not a root user. I need this to work on non rooted devices

Comment: @Lunchbox Problem is with incorrect db path. Did you specify db path like this: `String outFileName = "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/" + dbname;` ?

Comment: I solved the issue, will mark your answer as correct. Only with one slight change. I just got the path like this instead: getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("my_database_name"); Can you add it as add edit to your answer?

Comment: @Lunchbox also this is solution ;) nice touch and workaround.

Comment: Thanks, just changed the title as well. Realised that the question changed somewhat during the discussion

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to external storage.

Use this:

```
    public SQLite(Context context){
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.Separator +  
              DATABASE_NAME+".db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
```

Don't hard code the path.