# connecting an access database to my android app

Tags: java, android, database, ms-access

I have created an app in eclipse android sdk and I need to connect the database I created and I wonder if anyone can please send me a quick code to connect between them.
Information about this would be great too.

my database location is:

```
C:\Users\barw1_000\Desktop\Database(application)
```

and its name is:

```
SwimmingTraining
```

Comment: You are going to want to use sqlite or some other data storage mechanism that can actually be used when deployed to an android phone. You are not going to be able to directly use an Access database with an android app

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/691026/ms-access-database-connectivity-in-android

Comment: so can you send me information about that?

Comment: Copy the db in your project's `assets` folder. Then follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device