# Location of data file in app's installation directory?

Tags: java, android

I am using Maxmind Geo IP to read data from a database (in Java Android app). I have copied the database to the /src/main/assets folder. Below is a piece of code supplied by Maxmind to start reading from the database.

```
File database = new File("/path/to/GeoIP2-City.mmdb");
```

What is the correct path to use? I have tried:

```
"/data/data/com.mydomain.app/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb"
```

But that didn't work (file not found).

Comment: It's `/data/data/com.mydomain.app/databases/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb`

Comment: I've tried that, but still file not found.

Comment: Can you show the code where you copy the db from the assets folder to the path I indicated? And the code where you open the db?

Comment: Oh... I have to copy the file from the assets folder programmatically? With copying I meant I put the file in the "assets" folder of the project.

Comment: Not enough. There's another step. So, programmatically copy the db to the correct path (if not yet existing).

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device

Answer (score -1):

MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb
MaxMindDBFile CITY_DB    /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb

Comment: Thanks but this also doesn't work